# Telethon: how to mark message unread in channel?

Tags: telegram, telethon

I've created personalized channel for myself where I forward messages from other channels with Telethon.

Is there any way to mark them "unread" to see when new messages are coming?

Both forward and reading happens on the same account.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't get notifications for messages you send yourself. The only way would be to schedule the use the `schedule` parameter with a short (roughly half a minute delay). It should work with `send_message` when sent to your own chat, but I'm not sure if it works with `forward_messages`, and I don't know if it works when the target chat is not your own.

Comment: Schedule parameter hack works for messages, but not for forwards. But anyway thatj works for me. Thank you.